# ResourceValuesXmlParseException: Unknown android attribute

Tags: java, android, sip, voip, android-dialer

My build file is that than this problem occurred and I don't want to change this configuration to upload app in play store

### Configuration

```
android {  
   compileSdkVersion 27   
  buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'   
  useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'   
  defaultConfig {   
      applicationId 'com.easytelecom1' 
        minSdkVersion 14     
    targetSdkVersion 27   
   }
```

### Error

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':actionbarsherlock:generateDebugRFile'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.symbols.ResourceValuesXmlParseException: Unknown android attribute 'SherlockSpinner'
    at com.android.ide.common.symbols.ResourceValuesXmlParser.parseDeclareStyleable(ResourceValuesXmlParser.java:335)
    at com.android.ide.common.symbols.ResourceValuesXmlParser.parseChild(ResourceValuesXmlParser.java:261)
    at com.android.ide.common.symbols.ResourceValuesXmlParser.parse(ResourceValuesXmlParser.java:175)
    at com.android.ide.common.symbols.ResourceDirectoryParser.parseResourceDirectory(ResourceDirectoryParser.java:173)
    at com.android.ide.common.symbols.ResourceDirectoryParser.parseDirectory(ResourceDirectoryParser.java:119)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.GenerateLibraryRFileTask.doFullTaskAction(GenerateLibraryRFileTask.kt:100)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

Comment: `Unknown android attribute 'SherlockSpinner'`

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.symbols.ResourceValuesXmlParseException: Unknown android attribute 'SherlockSpinner'
```

Try to delete SherlockSpinner (I don't know if it exists), clean build, add it again, make project.